# Face recognition result in json data file

Tags: json, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I want to save the detected face json data file instead detected rectangle shape on image with level as name do anyone have any idea how can i save Recognized face in json. I am having problems to do so. I seriously need help in this issue.

AFTER running this code:

```
import os
import os.path
import pickle
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import face_recognition
from face_recognition.face_recognition_api import image_files_in_folder

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}


def predict(X_img_path, knn_clf=None, model_path=None,   distance_threshold=0.45):

if not os.path.isfile(X_img_path) or os.path.splitext(X_img_path)[1][1:] not in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
    raise Exception("Invalid image path: {}".format(X_img_path))

if knn_clf is None and model_path is None:
    raise Exception("Must supply knn classifier either thourgh knn_clf or model_path")

# Load a trained KNN model (if one was passed in)
if knn_clf is None:
    with open(model_path, 'rb') as f:
        knn_clf = pickle.load(f)

# Load image file and find face locations
X_img = face_recognition.load_image_file(X_img_path)
X_face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(X_img)

# If no faces are found in the image, return an empty result.
if len(X_face_locations) == 0:
    return []

# Find encodings for faces in the test iamge
faces_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(X_img, known_face_locations=X_face_locations)

# Use the KNN model to find the best matches for the test face
closest_distances = knn_clf.kneighbors(faces_encodings, n_neighbors=1)
are_matches = [closest_distances[0][i][0] <= distance_threshold for i in range(len(X_face_locations))]

# Predict classes and remove classifications that aren't within the threshold
return [(pred, loc) if rec else ("unknown", loc) for pred, loc, rec in zip(knn_clf.predict(faces_encodings), X_face_locations, are_matches)]




def show_prediction_labels_on_image(img_path, predictions):

pil_image = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)

for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
    # Draw a box around the face using the Pillow module
    draw.rectangle(((left, top), (right, bottom)), outline=(0, 0, 255))

    # There's a bug in Pillow where it blows up with non-UTF-8 text
    # when using the default bitmap font
    name = name.encode("UTF-8")

    # Draw a label with a name below the face
    text_width, text_height = draw.textsize(name)
    draw.rectangle(((left, bottom - text_height - 6), (right, bottom)), fill=(0, 0, 255), outline=(0, 0, 255))
    draw.text((left + 6, bottom - text_height - 8), name, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

# Remove the drawing library from memory as per the Pillow docs
del draw

# Display the resulting image
pil_image.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

# STEP 2: Using the trained classifier, make predictions for unknown images
for image_file in os.listdir("data/test"):
    full_file_path = os.path.join("data/test", image_file)

    # Find all people in the image using a trained classifier model
    # Note: You can pass in either a classifier file name or a classifier model instance
    predictions = predict(full_file_path, model_path="trained_model.json")

    # Display results overlaid on an image
    show_prediction_labels_on_image(os.path.join("data/test", image_file), predictions)
```

I am Getting Result like this:-
Caption box on image--
[image]

How do I get the result in json with the face recognition python module.
I want result in json Format
Like this:-

```
  [
    {
      "name": {
        "x": 548,
        "y": 245,
        "width": 166,
    "height": 166,
      },
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "x": 548,
        "y": 245,
        "width": 166,
    "height": 166,
      },
    },
{
      "name": {
        "x": 548,
        "y": 245,
        "width": 166,
    "height": 166,
      },
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "x": 548,
        "y": 245,
        "width": 166,
    "height": 166,
      },
    },

  ]
```

Comment: pls. read about how to [format your code on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that will help to make your question easier to read and understand. Thanks.

Comment: Use the values `name, (top, right, bottom, left)` and store in a dictionary.